# React event listeners on array of elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React render function eventually renders a set of elements:

```
data.map((element) => {
  return <Object onChange={this.onObjectChange} />;
});
```

My question is what is the appropriate way to figure out which object had its `onChange` method called when I receive the callback?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to the `onSubjectChange` function will have your event which contains the event information.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Right, but unless the object is aware of its own ordinality in the parent controller and passes that information along, how do I know which object is triggering the callback?

Comment: Is the ordinality important? You can access the element by `event.target`. Get its value, if it has one, by `event.target.value`.

Comment: You should also probably be adding a `key` for each generated element, since you're doing this in a `map` operation.

Comment: @DaveCooper - Right, so I have a key, is there a way to retrieve the key in the callback?

Comment: You should be able to do `<Object key={yourKeyHere} onChange={(e) => this.onSubjectChange(yourKeyHere, e)} />` and that should give you everything you need.

Comment: @dave that's creating a new function. OP is trying to avoid it. Using the event as your answer suggests is the best way to avoid creating a new function for every rerender.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, pass the ID or element to the component you're creating, then pass that reference back to your event handler.

```
handleObjectChange = id => {
  const object = data.find(id)
}

render() {
  return data.map((element, index) => (
    <Object onChange={this.handleObjectChange} key={element.id} id={element.id} />
  ))
  // or just pass element={element} to track the object itself, why not?
  // after all, every array item's key must be unique
}
```

In Object...

```
function change() {
  const { onChange, id } = this.props
  onChange(id)
}
```

Is your Object closed, or prefer not to add an extra property? You could try wrapping it.

```
class IdentifiedButton extends Component {
  handleClick = (event, ...args) => {
    const { id, onClick } = this.props
    onClick(event, id, ...args)
  }

  render() {
    const { id, onClick, ...props } = this.props
    return <Button onClick={this.handleClick} {...props} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the callback in a function and pass an identifier:

```
data.map(element => <Object onChange={event => this.onObjectChange(element.id, event)} />);
```

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do this without re-creating every callback on every render call?  React is going to see these as new functions (they are) and diff the rest of the tree because of it

Comment: In my understanding, the child components will always be rerendered when the parent is changed, independent of whether the props changed or not. Going through the react docs, [you can find similar patterns to the one proposed](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#examples) and I'm using it on several occasions in my own apps w/o issues. If the re-rendering of the child components cause performance issues, you could consider implementing [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in the children.

Comment: use key, and you could use another property on the component when calling the change...  if `<object.../>` is a custom component, you can have that component pass another property to the function assigned for the event.

Answer (score 0):

If rerendering your `Object` component won't cost you that much I would go with something like this

```
data.map(element => <Object onChange={() => this.onObjectChange(element)} />);
```

If `Object` component is quite heavyweight you better pass `element` to `Object` component and then pass it to `onChange` callback

```
data.map(element => (
  <Object
    key={element.id} 
    onChange={this.onObjectChange} 
    element={element}
  />
);

class Object extends React.Component {
  handleChange = () => this.props.onChange(this.props.element)

  render(){
    return (
      <input type='text' onChange={this.handleChange} />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating an anonymous function in every render, you could have a function that creates the handlers like this (I am using Todo App as an example):

```
createOnChangeEventHandler(todo) {
    const { onToggleClick } = this.props;

    this.handlers = this.handlers || {};
    if (!this.handlers[todo.id]) {
      this.handlers[todo.id] = () => onToggleClick(todo.id);
    }

    return this.handlers[todo.id];
  }
```

...
Then in `render()`

```
{todos.map(todo => (<Todo key={todo.id} onClick={this.createOnChangeEventHandler(todo)} />))}
```